# NSNotificationCenter Flow - Wait for postNotification in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

In my iOS app, I want to do a background task when the user opens up a new ViewController.  In this particular instance, I process some images on a server and return back the URL of a GIF created from the images.

In the same ViewController, I have a button that lets the user download the GIF.  I want to design for the case in which the user tries to download the GIF when it is still being created on the server.

The way I currently have it set up in my app is that I add a listener in ViewWillAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:nil name:@"generatedGIF" object:nil];
```

Then I process the GIF in the background with the method

```
[self generateSpinGIF];
```

Then in the method generateSpinGIf, I post a notification after the GIF has been created on the server:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"generatedGIF" object:self];
```

Separately, I have an IBAction to detect when the user taps the button to download the GIF.  At this point, I want to either download the GIF if it already exists or wait until the background process is done.

What is the way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using notifications, create a gcd queue in a member variable of your view controller. Use dispatch_async to create the GIF. When the user taps the button, use dispatch_sync on the same queue to retrieve the GIF. If the GIF already exists, the dispatch_sync will execute immediately. If the creation process has not yet completed, it will block until the creation is complete.